# How last thrown Exception contains previously thrown Exception?

Tags: java, oop, exception, stack-trace, fault-tolerance

How does the last exception thrown contain all previously thrown exceptions in java?

I read Fail Safe Exception Handling from 
[Fail Safe Exception Handling](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/fail-safe-exception-handling.html) and I am not able to get this point "One way to do so is to make sure that the last exception thrown contains all previously thrown exceptions."
How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

[`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) has two constructors that take another `Throwable` as the "cause" of this exception:

- [`public Throwable(String message, Throwable cause)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29);
- [`public Throwable(Throwable cause)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable%28java.lang.Throwable%29).

This can be used to constuct a chain of exceptions.

[`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) and [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) have similar constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an exception that contains its cause:

- [public Exception(String message, Throwable cause)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

So, you can navigate recursively into the cause, tracking it til the root.